# How to get updated list of AWS S3 bucket contents

Tags: meteor, amazon-s3

I have https://github.com/CollectionFS working well with the S3 storage adaptor.

If files can be added to the S3 bucket by other means (external to this application), those files do not exist in my collection.

It seems that my only alternative is to start from scratch and build something which regularly polls AWS to get an updated list of files but this feels like a bit of a nightmare with authenticated AWS urls etc.

Am I missing an easier way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, you are correct. CollectionFS merely creates a collection with the path of each file you've stored using that package. It won't have any knowledge of any other files that were added through another method.

Comment: Thanks Brian, good to know that I've not overlooked something obvious.