# Pulling images in from S3 bucket in Meteor

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-s3, collectionfs

I saw a lot of docs on how to upload files to S3 but my question is kind of reversed. I have a meteor app and i set up `collectionFS` in it. Now I have an S3 bucket with header images for each document inside my app. How do i reference it for an individual document? (if it helps, the `slug` for each document is correspondent to the image title `slug.jpg` in the bucket).

so far I have

```
var imageStore = new FS.Store.S3("careerImages", {
  // region: "my-s3-region", //optional in most cases
  accessKeyId: "my-value", //required if environment variables are not set
  secretAccessKey: "my-value", //required if environment variables are not set
  bucket: "ryf2.5", //required
  // ACL: "myValue", //optional, default is 'private', but you can allow public or secure access routed through your app URL
  folder: "header_images", //optional, which folder (key prefix) in the bucket to use 
  // The rest are generic store options supported by all storage adapters
  // transformWrite: myTransformWriteFunction, //optional
  // transformRead: myTransformReadFunction, //optional
  // maxTries: 1 //optional, default 5
});

CareerImages = new FS.Collection("careerImages", {
  stores: [imageStore]
});
```

and now i just wanna be able to figure out a way to display them in my templates.

Comment: @ChristianFritz i updated the question with some code. let me know if you need anything else

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312912/how-to-get-updated-list-of-aws-s3-bucket-contents what it's saying is that there is no way for me to access the collection. i guess i need to add them through meteor in the first place to show up in the collection